# What is the implicit contract for a property's type when used with the ConfigurationProperty attribute?

Tags: .net, configuration, typeconverter, configurationsection

As an example, I would like to serialize and deserialize a `System.Version` object as part of my application's custom configuration section.  I am attempting to do so with the following property declaration:

```
public class ConfigElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("ver", IsRequired = false, DefaultValue = "1.2.4.8")]
    public Version Ver
    {
        get { return (Version)this["ver"]; }
        set { this["ver"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, attempting to serialize or use this property (with or without the `DefaultValue`) yields the following exception message.

*System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException : The value of the property 'ver' cannot be converted to string. The error is: Unable to find a converter that supports conversion to/from string for the property 'ver' of type 'Version'.*

`System.Version.ToString()` writes the object to a well-known string format which is consumable by `System.Version.ctor(string)`, so it seems feasible for a "converter" to exist for this type.  Comparably, the `System.TimeSpan` type has similar methods and functions (`Parse` in-place of `.ctor(string)`) and the type works well with the configuration system (a converter must already exist).

How do I know if a type has a suitable converter?  What contract (implicit or otherwise) must such a type satisfy?

Comment: One way would be to try to deserialize it and see if you get this exception.

Comment: The Version class is not XML serialiable, all its properties are read-only.  Make your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the ConfigurationProperty to work, the type used must be associated with a [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) than knows how to convert from a string. ConfigurationProperty does have a [Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationproperty.converter.aspx) property, but alas, it's read-only. And, that's really bad luck, Version does not have an implicit TypeConverter declared either.

What you can do though, is add a [TypeConverterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute.aspx) to the Version class programmatically, and it will work around all these issues. So you need to basically call this line once in your program before accessing the configuration:

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(Version), new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(VersionTypeConverter)));
// ... you can call configuration code now...
```

with the following custom-made VersionTypeConverter:

```
public class VersionTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        return new Version((string)value);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
            return true;

        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well done, sir!  It is too bad, we can't register these types via app configuration or some event.  The former wouldn't be too difficult to enable though.